# use await inside callback (Microsoft Bot Framework v4 nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework, chatbot

I am trying to send the response back to `chatbot emulator` from inside callback.

```
async getUserDetails(step){
    console.log("inside get userdetaiuls modeiule")
    this.userDBObject.password = step.result;

   this.userDBMethod ( async function(response){
        console.log("inside callback return");
        console.log(response);
        await step.context.sendActivity(response); // not able to do this step
        return step.endDialog();
    });
}
async userDBMethod(callback){
request.post('#', 
        {form:{key: 'hi'}}, function (error, response, body) {
        callback("done");
});
}
```

The error which I'm getting is:

> (node:17424) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot
>   perform 'get' on a proxy that has been revoked
>       at D:\LCI\Usecases\statementBalance\lionsbot-src\bot.js:384:32
>       at Request._callback (D:\LCI\Usecases\statementBalance\lionsbot-src\bot.js:410:17)
>       at Request.self.callback (D:\LCI\Usecases\statementBalance\lionsbot-src\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:182:13)
>       at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
>       at Request. (D:\LCI\Usecases\statementBalance\lionsbot-src\node_modules\request\request.js:1161:10)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:182:13)
>       at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
>       at IncomingMessage. (D:\LCI\Usecases\statementBalance\lionsbot-src\node_modules\request\request.js:1083:12)
>       at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13) (node:17424) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
>   error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
>   without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
>   with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:17424) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

So how can I use await inside callback to send response back to the user.
Thanks !

Comment: Use `try/catch` to catch errors thrown in the Promise?

Comment: but right now important task is to send back the user response. which is in await step.context.sendActivity(response);

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) - a promise based HTTP client for node.js - rather than the request package. Since Axios is promise based, you can use async/await instead of callbacks. The resulting code falls more in line with the flow of the BotFramework. For more details, see the code snippet below and the [Axios Documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios).

```
async getUserDetails(step){
    this.userDBObject.password = step.result;
    try {
        const res = await axios.post('#', {form:{key: 'hi'}});
        await step.context.sendActivity("Done");
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        await step.context.sendActivity("Sorry, we were not able to complete your request.");
    } 
    return step.endDialog();
}
```